# Popup dialog box manager using PureMVC

Tags: flash, popup, puremvc

I am developing a a game in Flash using the PureMVC framework. From time to time I need to show dialog pop-up window to get a user response back (e.g. "Cancel", "OK" and other kinds of asynchronous user feedback) while "locking" the background for interactivity.

I need some management for my pop-ups: all pop-up notifications should be stacked up, so that if two (or more) pop-up messages are initiated at the same time I show them one by one.

What's the best practice here? Should I employ a proxy to manage my pop-ups (sounds unreasonable). How do I get feedback back from my dialog? using notifications?

Answer (score 0):

You can probably store popup instances in Proxy and manage them with commands.